# Pyqt qlabel failed to update after working fine for some time

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel

I create a gridlayout which consists of 30*30 qlabels, codes as follow:

```
num=30
def init_UI(self):
        self.chessboard = []
        for i in range(num):
            for j in range(num):
                label = QtWidgets.QLabel("")
                background_color = QColor(0, 0, 0)
                label.setAutoFillBackground(True)
                palette = QPalette()
                palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, background_color)
                label.setPalette(palette)

                self.chessboard.append(label)
                self.gridLayout.addWidget(label, i, j)
        self.gridLayout.setSpacing(0)
```

and then try to change the colors of them in a thread, codes as follow:

```
def flamboyant_show(self):
    while True:
        for i in range(num):
            for j in range(num):
                index = i * num + j
                palette = QPalette()
                palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, colors[random.randint(0, len(colors) - 1)])
                self.chessboard[index].setPalette(palette)
                time.sleep(0.1)


self.show_thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.flamboyant_show)
self.show_thread1.start()
```

It works fine for some time (about 30s) ,but then it stops updating the colors. However,When I click any button in the UI, it would come back to work and last for some time.

Could any one tell me the reason for this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Could you provide a minimal and complete example? But, first hint: use a `QTimer` instead of a thread + `time.sleep`

Comment: please provide a [mre]